# How to correctly include other ReST-files in a sphinx-project?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

My hand-written documentation/user-guide (written in ReStructuredText with sphinx) has become quite big so I started organize my .rst-files in sub-directories.

In the `index.rst` I'm including a `subindex.rst` of each sub-directory which itselfs includes other `.rst`-files for further sub-directories.

`index.rst`:

```
.. include:: subdir1/subindex.rst
.. include:: subdir2/subindex.rst
```

`subdir1/subindex.rst`:

```
.. include:: file1.rst
.. include:: file2.rst
```

In principle this works well, except that sphinx is recursively looking for `.rst`-files which it tries to parse. without changing the current-working dir. So, it fails when seeing `include:: file1.rst` inside `subdir1`.

I'm working around this issue by setting `exclude_pattern` to ignore my subdirs. This seems not right.

What would be the right way to include a `.rst`-file of a subdir?

Comment: Please read about for the `toctree` directive: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html

Comment: It should work if you change the include directives in subindex.rst to `.. include:: /subdir1/file1.rst` and `.. include:: /subdir1/file2.rst`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [toctree directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) should do what you want.

```
.. toctree::
    :glob:

    subdir1/*
    subdir2/*
```

The glob `*` will alphabetically sort files within `subdir`s. To avoid sorting, you could specify the order without globbing.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    subdir1/file2
    subdir1/file1
    subdir2/file1
    subdir2/file2
```

If you don't want individual pages but one huge page, you can invoke [make singlehtml](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-build).

Comment: How to add an external directory? Like `../subdir1/*`

Comment: That's exactly the issue I'm currently trying to resolve (referring to a file outside or above the root directory level of the active .rst - file): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626646/cannot-find-relative-path-to-local-file-in-restructuredtext-document-in-sphinx