# Cannot find relative path '../..' outside of root directory in Sphinx restructuredText: 'unknown document error'

Tags: python, python-sphinx, relative-path, restructuredtext

Even though I checked the relative path a million times (it is correct as measured from the document location wherein the reference is stated), still the error is thrown upon pushing the docs to [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild):

```
Warning, treated as error:
/codebuild/output/src192164467/src/docs/source/proj-repository-contents.rst:100:
unknown document: ../../src/lambda_functions/input/README.rst
```

The part where I reference the other [.rst](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/index.html) - document looks like so:

```
* input

    Supports the input ingestion pipelines.
    More details can be found in the :doc:`input Lambda functions <../../src/lambda_functions/input/README.rst>` - README.
```

**How** can I ensure that another document **outside the active parent directory** is found via e.g.

```
:doc:`some name <../../folder/filename.rst>`
```

**?**

---

**EDIT: more approaches which did not work**

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953127/12298276), one could include *absolute paths* into the `conf.py` - file like so:

```
SOURCE_PATH = os.path.join(LOCAL_PATH, '..', '..', 'src')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(SOURCE_PATH))
```

Next, I tried to refer to one of the READMEs with the following approaches, which all failed due to the same 'unknown document error':

- `<./lambda_functions/input/README.rst>`
- `</lambda_functions/input/README.rst>`
- `<lambda_functions/input/README.rst>`

Just for curiosity, I tried with the general root directory of the project, but it also failed:

```
<src/lambda_functions/input/README.rst>
```

As a last resort, I tried it with a direct path to the folder where the README-file is located:

```
LAMBDA_INPUT_PATH = os.path.join(LOCAL_PATH, '..', '..', 'src',
                                 'lambda_functions', 'input')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(LAMBDA_INPUT_PATH))
```

With this, I referred directly to the filename using `<README.rst>`, and even this failed.

Comment: Although for images, [this answer also applies to documents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714722/2214933).

Comment: Thanks, I tried out new approaches as detailed in the **Edit**. Yet, it seems to be impossible to refer to files above or outside the parent directory of the active via `:doc:`. In another document we have a working example using `.. include:: ../../../src/packages/dist/ATTENTION.rst`, maybe it depends on the type of referral (doc, include, figure, ...).

Comment: `include` is the only way I know to refer to a documentation file (not a module or extension) outside the documentation source directory. It's a common practice to include `CHANGES.txt` in the root of a project from the `docs/changes.rst` documentation file. Pyramid does this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pylons/pyramid/master/docs/changes.rst Sphinx uses the configuration key [`root_doc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-root_doc) to locate documentation source files relative to `conf.py`. Perhaps that is why `sys.path.insert` did not work?